# Getting a field with an array from an object, php

Tags: java, php, arrays, object, decoding

1. I send my json-encoded object on php;
2. When on php I work firstly with simple fields (int, string, data) of object, everything works fine.
3. When I try get array fields, I have ""}"" instead of [1,2,..n]
   (if I try php on hard code data, everything works fine)

My class (on Java)
1)

```
    public class Sight {
    public Sight() {
        this.id = -1;
        this.name = "";
        this.photo = "";
        this.info = "";
        this.area_id = -1;
        this.area = "";
        this.update_date = new Date();
        this.coordinates = "";
        this.categoryId = -1;
        this.category = "";
        this.other_categories = new ArrayList<>();
        this.tags_values = new ArrayList<>();
        this.rate = -1;
    }

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("object_id")
    private int id;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("photo")
    private String photo;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("info")
    private String info;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("area_id")
    private int area_id;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("area_name")
    private String area;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("update_date")
    private Date update_date;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("coordinates")
    private String coordinates;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("category_id")
    private int categoryId;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("category_name")
    private String category;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("other_categories")
    public List<Integer> other_categories;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("tags_values")
    public List<Integer> tags_values;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("success")
    private Boolean success;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("rate")
    private int rate;
}
```

2. php code:

```
    <?php
    require_once "conn.php";
    $result =  array();
    
    $content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $input = json_decode($content , true);
    
    //this lines only for debug!!! --->
    
      //to get json code of php-object
    array_push($result, json_encode($input));
    
      // to get array
    $temp = $content['other_categories'];
    array_push($result, json_encode($temp));
    
        //to get decoded array
    $temp = json_decode($content['other_categories'] , true);
    array_push($result, json_encode($temp));
    
    //these lines only for debag!! ---<
    
    $newname = $connection->real_escape_string($input['name']);
    $description = $connection->real_escape_string($input['info']);
    $area_id = $connection->real_escape_string($input['area_id']);
    $category_id = $connection->real_escape_string($input['category_id']);
    $tags = $connection->real_escape_string($input['tags_values']);
    $other_categories= $connection->real_escape_string($input['other_categories']);
    $photo = $connection->real_escape_string($input['photo']);
    $coordinates = $connection->real_escape_string($input['coordinates']);

    $query_insert_object =  "INSERT INTO `object`(`name`, `photo`, `info`, `area_id`, `update_date`, `coordinates`)
    VALUES ('$newname', '$photo', '$description', $area_id, NOW(), '$coordinates')";
    
    $query_id = "SELECT object_id FROM object ORDER BY object_id DESC LIMIT 1";
    if ($res = mysqli_query($connection, $query_insert_object)){
        
         $temp = mysqli_query($connection, $query_id);
         $id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($temp)['object_id'];
         $query_insert_main_category = "INSERT INTO `category_of_object`(`object_id`, `category_id`, `main`)
         VALUES ('$id','$category_id',1)";
         if ($res1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query_insert_main_category)){

             //code exactly go here, but cicles for and foreach never run ( $other_categories = null and $tags = null )
            for ($i = 1; $i < count($other_categories); $i++){
               
                
                $value=$other_categories[$i];
                 array_push($result, $value);
                $query_insert_other_categories = "INSERT INTO `category_of_object`(`object_id`, `category_id`, `main`)
                   VALUES ($id, $value ,0)";
                 if(!($res2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query_insert_other_categories)))
                 {
                     array_push($result, mysqli_error($connection));
                     echo "categories";
                 };
                 
            }
            foreach ($tags as $value) {
                array_push($result, $value);
                 $query_insert_tags = "INSERT INTO `various_of_objects`(`various_of_characteristic_id`, `object_id`)
                 VALUES ('$value','$id')";
                 
                 if (!($res3 = mysqli_query($connection, $query_insert_tags)))
                 {
                     array_push($result, mysqli_error($connection));
                     //echo "tags";
                 };
            }
            
            // Any of there line below I don't have in result! And all queries work fine on hard code data.
        } else{
            array_push($result, mysqli_error($connection));
            //echo "category";
            }
    } else {
        array_push($result, mysqli_error($connection));
       // echo "object";
    }
    
     echo json_encode($result);
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

3/ How you can see, I put in result some data for debug. Here is my result (from php), result.size() = 3 :
php object: (array_push($result, json_encode($input));)

```
result[0] = 
"{"area_name":"",
"area_id":12,
"category_name":"",
"category_id":1,
"coordinates":"50, 60",
"object_id":-1,"info":"",
"name":"ewdfew",
"other_categories":[2,3,4,5],
"photo":"ewdfew 2511.7730756090899.jpg",
"rate":-1,
"tags_values":[1],
"update_date":"Dec 5, 2020 11:46:49 PM"}"
```

As you can see, several fields are empty, but I don`t use them! I need arrays other_categories and tags_values

Arrays (

```
            array_push($result, json_encode($temp));
           $temp = json_decode($content['other_categories'] , true);
           array_push($result, json_encode($temp));:
```

and results

```
result[1] = ""{""
result[2] = "null"
```

Instead of Array I have this ""{"".

Thank you very much for each suggestion! I really need help.

Comment: After "Arrays(" I forget code line $temp = $content['other_categories'];

Comment: Your problem is that you are using $content that is not decoded. The decoded var is $input.

Comment: some suggestions: 1. no use query_id to get the las inserted id, instead use mysqli_insert_id($connection); 2. use foreach to iterate over $other_categories. You are using a "for" and it is not bad, but you are initializing $i = 1, then if there are only one category the loop not runs.

Comment: @Dharman but how is that different from every other question asked on stack overflow?

Comment: I didn't read almost any of your post but did you try the associative array flag in json_decode?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for all comments! So, I needed just remove

```
$connection->real_escape_string()
```

for Array-fields:

```
$content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$input = json_decode($content , true);
$tags = $input['tags_values'];
```

Now it works